# What is this white globe on my cats paw?

Tags: cats, skin-condition

It doesn't seem to bother him when I touched it.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could it be a tick or any other parasite? Or do you think it is part lf your cats skin/body?

Comment: please try to add a bit more information,where do you live,is your cat an indoor only or outdoors too,is this in a city or in the countryside.it does not look like a tick or any parasite i am familiar with.do you have other pictures of this and have your cat had this for some time? sorry for all the questions but i want to know what that is because i do not think i have seen it before.

Comment: I live in a city. He's indoors. I noticed a few days ago, so he's has this for at least ~3 days. Added another picture. I'm not sure but I don't think it changed size or color.

Comment: Really looks like a tick to me.

Comment: the shape looks like a tick and ticks can be very light grey-blueish and brown or red and the options for it to be anything else than a tick is limited i have removed hundreds of ticks from cats and dogs even from rabbits but still the color looks a bit off to me(in my opinion so not an answer).

Comment: I'm not so sure about this being a tick. The ticks I know have more of an oval shape (the body protrudes more from the skin). It could also be a blister filled with liquid. Those things sometimnes happen without any real cause. I would keep an eye on it for at least 2 more days. If it's suddenly disappeared, it was a tick. If it's still there and didn't grow *significantly*, it's a blister or something else in the skin.